# Pass a filter with a form in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to teach myself AngularJS, and I've been staring at this piece of code for so long, my eyes are starting to cross.

I have a JSON file of `cats` containing the properties `name`, `sex`, `color`, `pattern`, and `picture` for each `cat` object. (`sex` in this case is a Boolean; `0` for female and `1` for male. This will come back up soon.)

I use the following code to loop through the JSON file and print out a table of all `cat` objects, and it works correctly (and even pretties up the formatting a bit):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Sex</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Pattern</th>
    <th>Picture</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="kitty in cats">
    <td>{{kitty.name|capitalize}}</td>
    <td ng-if="kitty.sex == 0">Female</td>
    <td ng-if="kitty.sex == 1">Male</td>
    <td>{{kitty.color|capitalize}}</td>
    <td>{{kitty.pattern|capitalize}}</td>
    <td ng-if="kitty.picture"><img ng-src="{{kitty.picture}}" alt="{{kitty.name|capitalize}}"></td>
    <td ng-if="!kitty.picture">NO IMAGE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like *now* is to allow a user to click a checkbox, e.g. "Male", and have the view change to display all `cat` objects where `sex` is `1`. I can achieve this by replacing:

`<tr ng-repeat="kitty in cats">`

...with...

`<tr ng-repeat="kitty in cats | filter:{'sex': 1}">`

...but for obvious reasons, I would much prefer to have this functionality available dynamically, rather than hard-coded.

I've tried various ng-models as well as names, ids, and values on a given checkbox, but I have yet to figure out the correct syntax with which to pass the argument `1` to the repeat function, to have it filter the cats as necessary.

Does anyone have any ideas on how these two should be bound?

Comment: So you want to send Boolean value dynamically to filter when user clicks on checkbox. Is that correct what i understood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want this:
HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Sex</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Pattern</th>
    <th>Picture</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="kitty in cats | filter : {sex: genderFilter}">
    <td>{{ kitty.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ kitty.sex ? 'Male' : 'Female' }}</td>
    <td>{{ kitty.color }}</td>
    <td>{{ kitty.pattern }}</td>
    <td ng-if="kitty.picture">
      <img ng-src="{{kitty.picture}}" alt="{{kitty.name|capitalize}}">
    </td>
    <td ng-if="!kitty.picture">NO IMAGE</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" 
         ng-true-value="1" 
         ng-false-value 
         ng-model="genderFilter">Male
</label><br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" 
         ng-true-value="0" 
         ng-false-value 
         ng-model="genderFilter">Female
</label>
```

PLUNKER: http://plnkr.co/edit/av2cyzJmwxJLkqhSFnOv?p=preview

Comment: Much appreciated! This provided the exact functionality I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can send filter value dynamically based on selected checkbox value.

```
<table ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter : { sex: selectedGender }" style="width:300px">
```

verify this sample http://fiddle.jshell.net/w9darn8a/2/